# The Field of Real Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck on a problem for my abstract algebra class. I feel like it should be a basic proof, but I'm not sure where to go with it. The problem is the following:

Assume that $F$ is an ordered field, $a, b \in F$, and that the unity of $F$ is 1. Prove that $b > a > 0$ implies that $a^{-1} > b^{-1} > 0$.

I know the basic definition of an ordered field, and I think I may need to mess around with that to show what I need to. I'm just not sure which direction to take it in. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Axiom.$(x>0\land y>z)\implies x y>x z.$.....   Now if $b>a>0$ then $$ b^{-1}>a^{-1}\implies b\cdot b^{-1}>b\cdot a^{-1}\implies$$ $$\implies a=a\cdot (b\cdot b^{-1})>a\cdot (b\cdot a^{-1})=b,$$ a contradiction. So $b>a>0\implies a^{-1}\geq b^{-1}.$ But $b>a\implies b\ne a\implies a^{-1}\ne b^{-1}.$ So $b>a>0\implies a^{-1}>b^{-1}.$

And $b>0\implies b^{-1}>0$ because $(b>0\land b^{-1}<0)\implies$ $ 1=b\cdot b^{-1}<b\cdot 0=0\implies$ $ b=b\cdot 1<b\cdot 0=0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Just a quick question... I've never seen the notation that is used here: (x>0 ∧ y>z). What is the symbol '^'?

Comment: It means "and."

Comment: To the OP: .Do you know how to prove that $(-1)^2=1$ in any field?